# Alterar upload de imagem de mysql_query para PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Gostaria de alterar esse código que está funcionando com `mysql_*` para `PDO`:

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['enviar']) ) {
    $arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE cabecalho SET logo = '$logo");

    if ($update == '') {
        echo "<script language='javascript'>window.alert('Erro ao atualizar imagem!!!');</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script language='javascript'>window.alert('Imagem cadastrada com sucesso!!!');</script>";

        //referenciar a classe upload
        include("../Upload.class.php");

        $imagem = "";

        if( isset($_FILES["arquivo"]) ){
            $dir_dest = "../upload";

            //linha que faz o upload
            $upload = new Upload($_FILES['arquivo'], $dir_dest);

            // verifica se foi realizado corretamente o upload
            if ($upload->processed) {
                $imagem=$upload->file_dst_name;
            }
        }

        echo "<img src='../upload/$imagem'/><br /><br />";
        echo "<img src='../upload/mini/$imagem'/>";
    }
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="cadastro">
    Imagem do Logo
    <br /><br />
    Logo : <input type="file" name="logo" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" name="enviar">
</form>
```

Abraço à todos, e brigadão pela atenção.

Comment: muito boa sua pergunta, faça o seguinte coloque até aonde chegou e quais teste que fez assim posso te ajudar

Comment: Respondi sua pergunta, porém sua logica está errada. Você não passou a estrutura do banco, também não passou o conteudo do arquivo Upload.class.php. Melhorarei a resposta caso me forneça essas informações.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente é necessário uma conexao com o PDO, segue abaixo um exemplo.

```
$host="localhost";
$login="root"; // Seu login do banco de dados
$senha=""; // Sua senha do banco de dados
$db="nome_banco"; // Nome de sua base de dados
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$login,$senha);
```

Feito isso é necessário preparar suas queries, segue abaixo o código depois de finalizado:

> Porem você tem problemas em sua lógica, e não vai funcionar corretamente, mais o tratamento para usar o PDO é o exemplo abaixo. Você pode estudar a implementação do pdo no lugar do mysql_* acredito que entendendo como funciona seria melhor para você fazer seu desenvolvimento.

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$login="root"; // Seu login do banco de dados
$senha=""; // Sua senha do banco de dados
$db="nome_banco"; // Nome de sua base de dados
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$login,$senha);

if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
    $arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
    $update = $conn->prepare("UPDATE cabecalho SET logo = :logo"); //Preparo a string de conexão
    $update->bindParam(':logo', $logo); // Faço o bind dos parametros

    if(!$update->execute()){ //Executo a query
        echo "<script language='javascript'>window.alert('Erro ao atualizar imagem!!!');</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script language='javascript'>window.alert('Imagem cadastrada com sucesso!!!');</script>";

        //referenciar a classe upload
        include("../Upload.class.php");
        $imagem = "";
        if(isset($_FILES["arquivo"])) {
            $dir_dest = "../upload";
            //linha que faz o upload
            $upload = new Upload($_FILES['arquivo'], $dir_dest);
            // verifica se foi realizado corretamente o upload
            if ($upload->processed) {
                $imagem=$upload->file_dst_name;
            }
        }
        echo "<img src='../upload/$imagem'/><br /><br />";
        echo "<img src='../upload/mini/$imagem'/>";
    }
    $update->closeCursor(); //Encerro a conexão.
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="cadastro">

Imagem do Logo<br /><br />
Logo : <input type="file" name="logo" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" name="enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: Não entendi o voto negativo nessa resposta, ela é útil e descreve os procedimentos pra fazer o `update` que o op pediu com `PDO`.

Comment: Eu penso o mesmo Eduardo, mais acredito que a pergunta sim mereça um voto negativo pois ela foge um pouco do foco da comunidade. Ele deveria tirar duvidas de implementação do PDO independente para oque seja ('uploads, atualizações, inserções, consultas...') pois acho que sabendo isso o resto é só lógica na implementação.